# asp.net cant redirect form on submit

Tags: asp.net, forms, post, redirect

```
<form request="post" action="http://google.com">
<input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When im trying this code in my asp.net webforms app, i dont get redirected. The point is to redirect to another aspx page with some posted values from the form. Is there any other way to solve this? Jquery redirect + ajax post maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you wish to do that via server-side forms (which I see you didn't in your example although you mention webforms) you are in the "realm" of cross-page posting. This is a slightly different scenario since usually a webform will normally post to itself only.

The framework supports cross-page posting via a few particular steps as explained here:

[Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

[How to: Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but im looking for a client side solution

Comment: What do you mean client-side? Post via script?

Comment: Yes, like jquery $.post + redirect or something similar

Comment: You won't be able to post to a different domain via script because of the *same origin policy*.

Answer (score 1):

`request` is not valid attribute use `method="post"`.

```
<form method="post" action="http://google.com">
<input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```